# Retrive <b> value using Beautiful Soup and python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Below is the example of the html page. Trying to create a dataset where value under the tag `<b>` will be headers and value of tag `<span>` will be their value. how that can be done. please help.

```
<div class ="profile">

        <P class="info">
          <b>Full name</b>
          <span>Raju Kumar</span>
        </p>

        <P class="info">
          <b>DOB</b>
          <span>05/06/1992</span>
        </p>

        <P class="info">
          <b>DOB</b>
          <span>05/06/1992</span>
        </p>



</div>
```

Below is the my attempt to get `<b>` tag value as a header. but its only return the 1st `<b>` tag value.

```
header = [h.string for h in soup.find('p', class_='info').find_all('b')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list with the following line :

```
values = [(p.find('b').string, p.find('span').string) 
             for p in soup.find_all('p', class_='info')]
```

if you prefer a dictionary format :

```
dict_values = {p.find('b').string: p.find('span').string 
                  for p in soup.find_all('p', class_='info') }
```

**EDIT:**

If you need to build a dataframe,

you have the method [DataFrame.from_items](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_items.html), given a sequence of pairs :

```
values = [(p.find('b').string, p.find('span').string) 
             for p in soup.find_all('p', class_='info')]
value_df = pandas.DataFrame.from_items(values)
```

Or you can use [DataFrame.from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) :

```
dict_values = {p.find('b').get_txt():p.find('span').get_txt() 
                  for p in soup.find_all('p', class_='info') }
value_df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_values)
```

Comment: When I add `.get_txt()` with `p.find('b')` and `p.find('span')`. It works fine. but do you think that I can also make a dataframe where `p.find('b').get_text'` will be header and `p.find('span').get_text'` will be their values?

Comment: you can use the `DataFrame.from_dict` method, check the edit

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding this correctly, you need to loop twice:

```
header = [b.string for h in soup.find_all('p', class_='info') for b in h.find_all('b')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only finding the first `p` with `soup.find` - use `soup.find_all` like you did with the `b` tag

Comment: I tried that, but I get this error message - `AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'
`

Comment: @RajuSingh How did you define `soup`?